# VCR doesn't generate yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

RSpec test runs successfully, but VCR doesn't generate yml file.

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'vcr'

VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir     = 'spec/cassettes'
  c.hook_into :typhoeus
  # c.ignore_localhost         = false
  # c.default_cassette_options = { :record => :new_episodes }
end
```

**spec/smoothPayApi_spec.rb**

```
require 'smoothPayApi'
require 'spec_helper'

describe SmoothPayApi do

    before :each do
        @item = SmoothPayApi.new
        @token = ''
    end

    describe "#getToken" do

        # use_vcr_cassette

        it "gets token by calling gen_token_test" do
            VCR.use_cassette 'api/getToken' do

                return_info = @item.getToken('X3r82l89', 1)
                expect(return_info.message).to eq('success')
                @token = return_info.data

            end
        end
    end
end
```

SmoothPayApi::getToken uses Net::HTTP::Post.

I do this test in localhost. Is it the problem?

Comment: You are unlikely to get much help from posting github links rather than putting your code here.  Try to post the smallest possible sample that we can run that still exhibits the problem.  That said, it sounds like you're missing a 'require' somewhere.

Comment: I added source contend. Would you please check?

Comment: Same diagnosis as before.  Assuming you have installed the 'vcr' gem (I've never used it personally), you'll also need "require 'vcr'" somewhere in your code or ruby will have no idea what 'VCR' is referring to

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't using Typhoeus to make your HTTP requests but you are having VCR hook into it.  You need to have VCR hook into a library that can intercept the requests you are making.  The [VCR docs](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-9-2/docs/configuration/hook-into) have a list.  Based on this statement:

> SmoothPayApi::getToken uses Net::HTTP::Post.

...it sounds like you want to use `hook_into :webmock` rather than `hook_into :typhoeus`.