# Use variable as modified in previous example

Tags: ruby, rspec

Here is my RSpec test code:

```
describe SmoothPayApi do
    before :all do
        @item = SmoothPayApi.new
        @token = ''
    end
    describe "#getToken" do
        it "gets token" do
            VCR.use_cassette 'api/getToken' do
                return_info = @item.getToken('X3r82l89', 1)
                expect(return_info.success).to eq('success')
                $token = return_info.data
            end
        end
    end
    describe "#pay" do
        it "gets a response from pay" do
            VCR.use_cassette 'api/pay' do
                return_info = @item.pay($token, '30', [{"id" => 1, "name" => 'margherita', "price" => 9.99, "quantity" => 1, "category" => 'pizzas', "code" => 'abcd'}, {"id" => 2, "name" => 'alex', "price" => 7.99, "quantity" => 3, "category" => 'pizzas', "code" => 'abcd'}])
                expect(return_info.message).to eq('30')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

In the second `it` example, I need to use the value of `$token` as is evaluated in the first `it` example. But `$token` doesn't work correctly in the second example. How can I do this? I tried using `let`, but I couldn't do this.

Comment: WTF is `$` in `$token`? Shouldn’t the be commercial at `@`?

Answer (score 1):

`$token` doesn't work, because you meant `@token`. But that wouldn't help you very much, because when you run your second test on its own, `@token` is empty, but the *pay* method needs a valid token.

So the rule is: Do not make your tests depend on each other! First of all you should always be able to run a single test on it's own. Then if a test fails, the root cause should always be found in this test itself, not in other ones. Finally you can run your tests in a randomized order (to find problems with interdependent tests). It is then never guaranteed that your token creation test will run before the one which uses it.

So never use global variables and also avoid using instance variables in your tests. It is always better to use `let`.

You could make the token creation a helper function and call it whenever you need a token. But the question is: do you really need to? It may be best to rearrange things (conceivably by using stubs if your api calls have side effects), so that you can specify an arbitrary token for the *pay* method. You stub your requests with VCR, so *you* specify the all the data and you *know* the token. So why not set the token explicitly in a `let`?

Comment: Yes, I meant @token. It's typing issue. Sorry.

Comment: I can't use arbitrary token value. I have to get it from getToken api.
How can we write helper function with let? Moveover I have to make the VCR cassette work, but it doesn't. Please see my another question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856801/vcr-doesnt-generate-yml-file

Comment: Helper function: just write a `def get_smooth_api_token ... end` outside your tests and then for example `let(:token) { get_smooth_api_token ... }`. The only key point is that you get your token without relying on another test.
Arbitrary token: I'm not using _VCR_ so i can't help you with this. I'm using _webmock_ directly and stubbing out all the interactions with my REST servers programmatically. So the backend functionality is always simulated (the backend doesn't even need to run) and i can send and return any values i like.